# Vbox into BorderPane

Tags: javafx

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage)
{

    btn1 = new Button();
    btn2 = new Button("h1");
    btn3 = new Button("h2");
    btn.setText("Click me please!");

    BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
    HBox pane2 = new HBox();
    pane2.getChildren().add(btn1);
    pane2.getChildren().add(btn2);
    pane2.getChildren().add(btn3);
    pane.setCenter(pane2);


    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 700, 550);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("The Click Me App");
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

i want my buttons to be in center of BorderPane.... What am i doing wrong?  help please. Right now they are at top position.

Comment: How do you distinguish top and center, if you only add a center node???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with :

```
pane.setCenter(pane2);
pane2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
```